# binary outputs are different in hash SHA256

Tags: python, vb.net

SHA256 hashing output is different in two codes, input is same so outputs should be identical, the code seems to be fine, I can't understand why it produces different results. What is wrong with it?

**VB.NET CODE**

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim temphashstring As String = "1a"
        temphashstring = hashed(temphashstring)
        T7.Text = StringToAsciiBits(temphashstring)

End Sub

Public Function StringToAsciiBits(ByVal inputstring As String) 'Convert string text to binary text

        Dim bitsAsString As String
        Dim Re As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For Each Character As Byte In System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputstring)
            Re.Append(Convert.ToString(Character, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"))
            'Re.Append(" ") 'put one space (" ") after every 8 bits to view easily by human eye
        Next
        bitsAsString = Re.ToString.Substring(0, Re.ToString.Length - 0)


        Return bitsAsString
    End Function

Public Function hashed(ByVal inputstring As String) As String

        'Encode by UTF8
        Dim pt As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
        Dim ptBytes() As Byte = pt.GetBytes(inputstring)
        Dim ptSBytes() As Byte = New Byte(ptBytes.Length - 1) {}
        'Copy plaintext bytes to array.
        Dim num As Integer
        Dim hash As HashAlgorithm
        'hashing algorithm class.
        hash = New SHA256Managed()
        ' Compute hash

        For num = 0 To ptBytes.Length - 1
            ptSBytes(num) = ptBytes(num)
        Next num

        Dim hashBytes As Byte()
        hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(ptSBytes)
        ' Convert into a base64-encoded string.

        Dim hashValue As String
        hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes)
        hashed = hashValue 'return hashvalue
    End Function
```

Input: `1a`

Output in binary: `0111000001111010001011110101000001001101001101010101101001000001011010110111000001001001010010000100101101000010001010110011010000110100010001000110100101001001010100110100000101100010011010010011011001110111011010000100000100111000011010010101001001010111011011000100111001110101001101100100100001010110011110100100100101101110011011010101010100111101`

**PYTHON CODE**

```
import hashlib, struct
tempheader = "1a"
print map(bin, map(ord,hashlib.sha256(tempheader).digest()))
```

Input: `1a`

Output in binary: `'0b10100111', '0b111111', '0b11001111', '0b110011', '0b10010110', '0b1000000', '0b10010010', '0b10010010', '0b111', '0b101000', '0b11111', '0b10111000', '0b11100000', '0b111000', '0b10001000', '0b1001000', '0b110', '0b11100010', '0b11101011', '0b1000', '0b1000000', '0b11110010', '0b100100', '0b1010110', '0b10010100', '0b11011011', '0b10111010', '0b11101', '0b1011100', '0b11001000', '0b10011110', '0b1100101'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me why you are going via a Base64 string in the VB version. You don't do that in the Python version, so you should expect the results to be different.

Here is similar code *without* using Base64:

```
Function SHA256BytesAsBinary(s As String) As String
    Dim pt As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    Dim ptBytes() As Byte = pt.GetBytes(s)
    Dim hash = New SHA256Managed()
    Dim bb = hash.ComputeHash(ptBytes)

    Return String.Join(" ", bb.Select(Function(x) Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, "0")))

End Function
```

So,

```
Console.WriteLine(SHA256BytesAsBinary("1a"))
```

Outputs:

> 10100111 00111111 11001111 00110011 10010110 01000000 10010010 10010010 00000111 00101000 00011111 10111000 11100000 00111000 10001000 01001000 00000110 11100010 11101011 00001000 01000000 11110010 00100100 01010110 10010100 11011011 10111010 00011101 01011100 11001000 10011110 01100101